# How to test if the stock market (NYSE) is currently open/closed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I am writing a stock market-related app, and would like to include an indicator of whether the stock market (NYSE) is currently open/closed. The Apple "Stocks" app on the iPhone includes this information. I figure the Stocks app is testing something from Yahoo since the quotes are from there and they link to Yahoo finance directly. However, for all my searching around both YQL, Stack Overflow, and the web I can't find a direct query.

Is there a way to query whether the NYSE is currently open/closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As provided by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Stock_Exchange#Trading)

> The NYSE is open for trading Monday through Friday between 9:30 am –
>   4:00 pm ET, with the exception of holidays declared by the Exchange in
>   advance.

You can easily hard code this or have a table in a DB with the holidays populated. Then use the time and time zone of the device to see if the NYSE is open or closed.

Comment: +1: no need for overkill. if NYSE market is closed when it shouldn't be your customers will hear of it on TV news :)

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but this isn't really the answer I'm hoping for. I think there must be a programmatic way - if not a direct query, then at least checking the current quote of a heavily traded stock and seeing if it is within the last X minutes or something like that. Using a hardcoded table means also hooking up to a web service of some kind to keep it updated for future years, with in-app updates. I'd love to know what Apple's own Stocks app does. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @DamienDelRusso, I dont know of another way but I would suggest not to over engineer, where a simple hack would work. If you go to the NYSE website, it provides a schedule for the next 3 years http://corporate.nyx.com/en/holidays-and-hours/nyse?sa_campaign=/internal_ads/homepage/08262008holidays. In my experience,  originations like the NYSE, follow a very strict schedule. The last time I can remember it did not follow its own schedule was 9/11, when it closed for 4 sessions.

Comment: Please note that NYSE is managed by DMMs on the floor who manually close out stocks and so each individual stock can close any time from 4-4:30pm.

Comment: Updated URL for holidays, hours, etc.: https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars

Answer (score 6):

It appears Apple provides a service with this information.

### Example/tl;dr:

Make the following `curl` call:

```
curl "http://wu-quotes.apple.com/dgw?imei=42&apptype=finance" -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf−8'?><request devtype='Apple_OSX' deployver='APPLE_DASHBOARD_1_0' app='YGoAppleStocksWidget' appver='unknown' api='finance' apiver='1.0.1' acknotification='0000'><query id='0' timestamp='`date +%s000`' type='getquotes'><list><symbol>GE</symbol></list></query></request>"
```

(You may have to substitute the `imei` parameter with a different random number)

This will return a response similar to the following (I've formatted the XML and removed the irrelevant parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result type="getquotes" timestamp="1405539220">
    <list count="1" total="1">
      <quote>
        ...
        <!-- Verify that this is the exchange you are interested in -->
        <exchange>NYSE</exchange>
        ...
        <!-- 0 means market is closed, anything else means its open -->
        <status>1</status>
        ...
      </quote>
    </list>
  </result>
</response>
```

Look for the `<status>` element. If the value is `0`, the NYSE is closed, otherwise the NYSE is open.

### Details

Apple provides a service, which the MacOS Stocks Dashboard widget uses to determine if the markets are open or close (presumably the iPhone app uses it as well). This service is undocumented, as far as I know, but this answer attempts to document information pertinent to your question.

The service is located at the following endpoint URL:

http://wu-quotes.apple.com/dgw?imei=(UID)&apptype=finance

(You may simply use a random number for the UID)

The service is really for obtaining stock quote information, but in the response, there is a `status` property, which seems to correspond to if the market that the stock is traded in is open or close. To make a call, post the following XML to it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf−8'?>
<request devtype='Apple_OSX' deployver='APPLE_DASHBOARD_1_0' app='YGoAppleStocksWidget' appver='unknown' api='finance' apiver='1.0.1' acknotification='0000'>
  <query id='0' timestamp='{{millis since epoch}}' type='getquotes'>
    <list>
      <symbol>{{stock symbol}}</symbol>
      <!-- More symbols -->
    </list>
  </query>
</request>
```

(Make sure the Content-type header is set to "text/xml").

Since you stated that you are interested in NYSE, you'd post the symbol for a company like GE (which is traded on the NYSE, as in my example above). If you are interested in, say, NASDAQ, you'd post a NASDAQ-traded company (e.g., AAPL).

The response you get should be in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result type="getquotes" timestamp="1405539220">
    <list count="1" total="1">
      <quote>
        <!-- quote details here -->
      </quote>
      <!-- more quotes here if you submitted more than one symbol -->
    </list>
  </result>
</response>
```

Within the `<quote>` element:

1. Look for the `<exchange>` element to make sure it matches the exchange you are looking for (e.g., "NasdaqGS", "NYSE").
2. Look for the `<status>` element. A value of `0` means stock markets are closed. Any other value means they are open.

The Stocks widget iterates through all the symbols it is configured for, and considers the markets open if and only if *all* quotes have non-zero statuses.

For more details, please refer to `/System/Library/WidgetResources/.parsers/stocksParser.js` which should be available on every Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Finnhub.io provides this function.  Specifically the Python interface to the function would look like:

import finnhub
finnhub_client = finnhub.Client(api_key="")
print(finnhub_client.market_status(exchange='US'))

You can get a free authentication key from Finnhub, and plug it into the  api_key="" parameter.  I'm reasonably confident that the free key would give you authority to use this function.